# How to define css styles for a vue.js component when registering that component?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, stylesheet, vue-component

I am able to register a custom vue.js component with

```
// register
Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: '<div class="my-class">A custom component!</div>'
})
```

Also see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

How can I include css classes for my component?

I would expect something like

```
 Vue.component('my-component', {
      template: '<div class="my-class">A custom component!</div>',
      css: '#... my css stylesheet...'
    })
```

but there does not seem to be a `css` option.

I know that I could

a) define all css classes in a global css stylesheet or

b) use singe-file-vue-components (would require build tool supporing *.vue files, see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html)

but I would prefer to

c) specify a css stylesheet for the component when registering the component.

=> How to do so?

Comment: Why would you not use webpack along with vue-loader? That would allow you to import CSS in your components as well. I feel the great vue-templates that come along with Vue is what really makes Vue stand out. You basically want single-file components but not the tools that enable you to use them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue 2 component styles without Vue loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42765262/vue-2-component-styles-without-vue-loader)

Comment: @connexo - not OP, but as someone for whom Web stuff is only a minor sideline these days, **the**  #1 thing that drew me to Vue rather than one of the zillion other frameworks was the fact that you don't need a big honking Node-based build stack to use it productively. Yes, there's a threshold of app complexity where it's probably worth biting that bullet, but it's quite a high threshold.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> there does not seem to be a css option.

That is correct. You cannot do what you describe. The [documentation on single file components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html#ad) is pretty clear that one of the advantages is that you can do this with them and cannot do it without them.

> In many Vue projects, global components will be defined using
> `Vue.component`, followed by `new Vue({ el: '#container' })` to target a
> container element in the body of every page.
>
> This can work very well for small to medium-sized projects, where
> JavaScript is only used to enhance certain views. In more complex
> projects however, or when your frontend is entirely driven by
> JavaScript, these disadvantages become apparent:
>
> [...]
> **No CSS support** means that while HTML and JavaScript are
> modularized into components, CSS is conspicuously left out

Comment: Ok, thank you for clarification. I want to keep the number of dependencies in my project small. I am new to vue.js  and I am still wondering if I want to include it at all. Now I consider two main options: #I. Also include the build tool dependencies as suggested by connexo or #II. stick to vanilla web components. The web component html files would allow to specify css classes and would not require specific build tools. However, dynamically importing those html files might become tricky.

Comment: I have come to this answer multiple times due to people underestimating this and moving to answers below it. Answers that suggest that component should insert css on mount will try to inser it multiple times. No Do not check if it already exist. In your application simply add a new stylesheet somewhere in component folder and include it in. Upload your css to a cdn and put it in your html file directly instead of doing any hacks below. Add style tag in document if its just related to that page and compoent. Its like any js library that comes with css for example bootstap.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a way to achieve what you're looking for:

```
export const ContactUs = Vue.component(
    'mycomponent-contact-us'
    ,{
        props: {
            backgroundColor: {
                type: String
                ,required: false
                ,default: "red"
            }
        }
        ,data: function(){
            return {
                
            }
        }
        ,template: `
            <div>
                <span class='contact_us_text' >Contact Us Component and its bg color will be {{backgroundColor}}</span>
            </div>
        `
        ,mounted: function(){
            var css_text = `
            .contact_us_text{
                color: `+this.backgroundColor+`;
            }
            `;
            var css = document.createElement('style');
            css.type='text/css';
            css.setAttributeNode( document.createAttribute('scopped') );
            css.appendChild(    document.createTextNode( css_text )     );
            this.$el.appendChild(   css     );
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: full credit goes to @smallscript above for pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

Its true that you cannot add `<style>` inside a Vue template or add CSS within
component directly, unless you bind it or define your css globally. But you can create a custom component that will dynamically do it for you. [sample](https://gist.github.com/jkga/0ea90663aaad46030740197a73c37a9f)

Comment: Looks like you write 50 lines of code to get a STYLE element back after VUE forced you not to do this.

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that **Vue** components are *effectively* macros.

Where `render` is the substitution function, and the `vueDefinition` (`defn3` below) is effectively a `class` for the given `tagName`.

A `template` is just a convenient *syntactic-sugar* shorthand that will be `compiled` *(with some vue-usage pattern restrictions)* into a `render` *function* if you don't provide your own `render` function.

```
const defn3 = {
  tagName: 'ae-css',
  mounted() {
    const vueDefinition = this.$options;
    this.$el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(vueDefinition.css));
  },
  css: `
    * {
      color: blue;
    }
  `,
  render(h) {
    return h('style');
  }
}
Vue.component(defn3.tagName, defn3);
```

With that *solution* in hand, there are a number of good reasons why you probably don't want something as simplistic as what I just provided.

Namely, you want to have your **css** *modularized* such that it does not affect any aspects of your page you did not intend it to. For that, you either need carefully designed **css** rules with your intended inheritance and scope; probably using a `class=..`.  But a better approach would be to just use Vue's facilities that offer similar capabilities automatically.

If you want to use modern browser architecture capabilities for this, then you might want your components to be real browser DOM `WebComponents` that make use of the **shadowDOM** and keep your internal elements and styles encapsulated within a `shadowRoot`. See [this library](https://github.com/Smallscript-Corp/vue-web-component-plugin), for doing that in **Vue**.

Comment: awesome ! but can you guide who i can refer to my property in that css string.

Lets say my component has a backgroundColor prop.

Comment: Aha! figured it out. Thank you for pointing in the right direction :)
defined css string in the mounted function and then used plain js to create style element, define its type as text/css and then using $el.appendChild added that style element.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed a style tag within your template root element:

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
      template: `
      <div class="my-class" my-component>
            A custom component!

            <style>
                  .my-class[my-component] {
                        // ... my-component styles
                  }
            </style>
      </div>
      `
})
```

Comment: This is not documented by the way, using a scoped style may not affect the container/parent of your style tag node

Comment: Vue3 rejects this approach with the warning: "Template compilation error: Tags with side effect (<script> and <style>) are ignored in client component templates." :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.$el.style.cssText = "border: 5px solid blue;"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).