# vue.js custom css for a component (Without webpack and vue-loader)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Using Vue Router to load the components.

Note that i am not using webpack or vue-loader.

Here is a sample component that get loaded by vue - router

```
export default {
    name: 'Abc',
    template:'<div>Now .. i can't add style element here :(. So where should i add it </div>',
    data(){
        return {
             message:' new message'
        }
    },
}
```

Where can i add css  styles. I don't care about css scoped if it is not possible.

Don't want to use render functions ( https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function#The-Data-Object-In-Depth ) .. as creating the dom structure would kill me

Comment: Without webpack you cannot modularize CSS as mentioned in the Vue [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html#Introduction). Most of the vue conponents out there provide a CSS file to be included in the head tag fo such cases. So effectively you have two choices a separate CSS file or inline-css in your template code.

Comment: yeah .. for now i have used the head css file,,

Answer (score 1):

[As is stated in this answer, you can't define separate CSS in a Vue component using something like `css` like you can define HTML using `template`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49053882/8230810)

That being said, there are a few ways you can define CSS for specific components/elements:

---

**Scoped CSS**

You can define a `style` to be scoped to a component:

*App.vue*

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <RedComponent/>
    <NotRedComponent/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import RedComponent from "./components/RedComponent";
import NotRedComponent from "./components/NotRedComponent";

export default {
  components: {
    RedComponent,
    NotRedComponent
  }
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

*RedComponent.vue*

```html
<script>
export default {
  template: "<div>I am red</div>"
};
</script>

<style scoped>
div {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

*NotRedComponent.vue*

```
<script>
export default {
  template: "<div>I am not red</div>"
};
</script>
```

[See this live here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/y20mk13m4z)

---

**CSS Classes and IDs**

You can give elements classes and IDs in order to select them with CSS, and just have a separate CSS file. Note: this is not unique to Vue.

*App.vue*

```html
<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  template: '<div><p class="red">I am red</p><p>I am not red</p></div>'
};
</script>
```

*index.css*

```html
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

[See this live here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/9jxlx3yo0y)

You can reference this `index.css` file from anywhere (within reason) - for example, in my live demo it is referenced from within `index.html` itself (something like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />` within the `<head>` tag will do).

---

**Inline styles**

For this, using backticks (`) rather than quotes will make your life easier. Another benefit of using backticks is the fact that you can span your template over multiple lines.

*App.vue*

```html
<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  template: `<div>
    <p style="color: red">I am red</p>
    <p>I am not red</p>
  </div>`
};
</script>
```

[See this live here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/54o07w27jn)

---

Personally, I've never found a use-case where scoped CSS won't do the trick, even with vue-router, but those are some alternative options if you can't use it for whatever reason.

Comment: for RedComponent.vue : what would be the return type : application/javascript or text/html

Comment: are you sure it was without webpack

Comment: I think `scoped` does use webpack actually, as Vue needs to add specific data tags to the individual elements in order to scope them properly when it compiles... the other two options should work fine without webpack though.

Comment: I don't understand your question about return type - RedComponent.vue is a Vue component, just kept in a different file.

Comment: yeah .. different file for RedComponent.vue .. i tried both application/javascript and  text/html MIME for it, both failed to import in the script .. like import {z} from 'a/b';

Comment: You probably don't need the curly braces as it exports the component by default. See App.vue for that example - `import RedComponent from "./components/RedComponent";`

Comment: i mean ,, in the RedComponent i had a dependency of another component let say BlueComponent.  import {z,BlueComponent,y,w} from 'a/b';  it works fine without <template></template><script></script>

Comment: Any dependencies that RedComponent has should be imported within the <script> tags of RedComponent, above the `export default` section (e.g. [here](https://gist.github.com/chrisvfritz/1c9f2daea9bc078dcb47e9a82e5f7587))... I don't understand what you're getting at. If my answer doesn't solve your problem, could you please clarify what you're struggling with in your original question?

Comment: Getting :   Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.  Also looking for scoped css.

Comment: Ah, yeah I forgot you need something like webpack to load vue files into JS... [this guy](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/cannot-import-vue-components-in-es6/30943) suggests you use something like [http-vue-loader](https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/http-vue-loader) to get around this. I've not tried it myself though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any CSS library like Bootstrap, Bulma etc, and add css classes directly in template like the following.

In `head` section of your page add bootstrap reference link and that's it.

```
template: `<div class="container">Boostrap</div>`
```

Comment: cannot add to head section of the page to reduce page load time

Comment: Definitely, it is not recommended to include in `head` section. I was telling about how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use `.vue` files without webpack (vue-loader) you can have a look at [vue3-sfc-loader](https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue3-sfc-loader).

> **vue3-sfc-loader**
> Load .vue files dynamically at runtime from your html/js. No node.js
> environment, no (webpack) build step needed.

<sub>(disclamer: author here)</sub>