# How to target a component in svelte with css?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-component

How would I do something like this:

```
<style>
Nested {
    color: blue;
}
</style>

<Nested />
```

i.e. How do I apply a style to a component from its parent?

Comment: What parent?  I see no parent here.

Comment: Just add a class to your Nested component `<Nested class="custom"/>`. https://stackoverflow.com/q/42765262/6809926

Comment: @AntoineF that doesn't work in svelte. It thinks that the class is a property, I think.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss that is the code in the parent.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to pass props to the parent component with export let, then tie those props to class or style in the child component.

You can either put a style tag on the element in the child you want to style dynamically and use a variable you export for the parent to determine the value of a style directly, then assign the color on the tag like this:

```html
<!-- in parent component -->

<script>
import Nested from './Nested.svelte';
</script>

<Nested color="green"/>
```

```html
<!-- in Nested.svelte -->

<script>
export let color;
</script>

<p style="color: {color}">
    Yes this will work
</p>
```

Upside here is flexibility if you only have one or two styles to adjust, downside is that you won't be able to adjust multiple CSS properties from a single prop.

or

You can still use the :global selector but just add a specific ref to the element being styled in the child like so:

```html
<!-- in parent component -->

<script>
import Nested from './Nested.svelte';
</script>

<Nested ref="green"/>

<style>
:global([ref=green]) {
    background: green;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: .5rem;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!-- in Nested.svelte -->

<script>
export let ref;
</script>

<p {ref}>
    Yes this will work also
</p>
```

This ensures global only affects the exact ref element inside the child it's intended for and not any other classes or native elements. You can see it in action [at this REPL link](https://svelte.dev/repl/c6b1e24a6f0844de8b032b0c23e928ee?version=3.17.3)

Comment: The `ref` above is just an attribute, so that global CSS will leak out and affect any component with an attribute of `ref=green`.

Answer (score 17):

The only way I can think of is with an additional `div` element.

**App.svelte**

```html
<script>
    import Nested from './Nested.svelte'    
</script>

<style>
    div :global(.style-in-parent) {
        color: green;
    }
</style>

<div>
    <Nested />  
</div>
```

**Nested.svelte**

```html
<div class="style-in-parent">
    Colored based on parent style
</div>
```

**Multiple Nested elements**

You could even allow the class name to be dynamic and allow for different colors if you use multiple `Nested` components. Here's a [link to a working example](https://svelte.dev/repl/eee5cf2ad77d4703a8bab5c7522322bc?version=3.6.7).

Comment: As I see you use :global so it's not targeting only inside the Nested Component, but all class `style-in-parent` inside the div. I tried it [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/fa67efdea32448e2895c1e5e7fee9458?version=3.6.7).

Comment: Ah right, good catch. I think the next step is to understand your use case better and why you try to style from the parent component.

Comment: In order to avoid leaking in the same component, you should add a class known to be unique, once again in the same component (svelte will add a hash preventing it from leaking outside. Here's an variation of @MikeNikles example: https://svelte.dev/repl/09b33283d787480cb30cab35d5b9d0a0?version=3.6.7

Answer (score 12):

You could use inline styles and $$props...

```
<!-- in parent component -->

<script>
import Nested from './Nested.svelte';
</script>

<Nested style="background: green; color: white; padding: 10px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold" />
```

```
<!-- in Nested.svelte -->

<script>
    let stylish=$$props.style
</script>

<div style={stylish}>
    Hello World
</div>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/7cd2fc19f24c42b8a1ddf849b4df1b34?version=3.24.0)

Comment: One-liner for Nested.svelte: `<div style={$$props.style}>`

Comment: This seems to be just what OP asked for, are there any downsides to doing it this way? Looks very straight-forward!

Comment: @MartinGunnarsson what if you are using library components? Then you have to go to the source code to add props into divs

Comment: @cikatomo what will be a good solution in your opinion for headless library components like https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bojalelabs/headless-svelte-ui to enable us to add props to divs?

Comment: @ayooluwaalfonso sorry, I really don't know

Comment: I found using $$props in a component caused it to get updated more frequently. It was better to have custom props and svelte would more accurately determine if a component updated or not.

Answer (score 8):

using `:global(*)` is the simplest solution.

No need to specify a class in the child if you want to style all immediate children for example

In the parent component:

```
<style>
  div > :global(*) {
    color: blue;
  }
<style>

<div>
  <Nested />
<div>
```

Nested will be blue.

Comment: This is the best and most simple solution because you can target Components that are more than 1 level Nested.

Answer (score 5):

Update for 2023, you can wrap your style tags in svelte:head which will put them in the head, removing them from the scope context.

```svelte
<svelte:head>
  <style>
    div { color: red };
  </style>
</svelte:head>
```

This snippet will make all div elements have the color "red". As such, I'd recommend using this sparingly (I'd probably only use it for scripts/content in a legacy way). Only because debugging "why is everything red" will be impossible for projects with significant routes.

The, iirc, "documented" way is through CSS variables.

```
<!-- Nested.svelte -->
<div>
  <slot />
</div>

<style>
  div { color: var(--nested-color, inherit); }
</style>
```

===

```
<!-- Parent.svelte -->
<div>
  <Nested>
    Applesauce
  </Nested>
</div>

<style>
  div {
    --nested-color: red;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Life saver! `<svelte:head><style>` is the only thing that worked correctly.

Comment: Good solution!!

Answer (score 3):

I take a look and found nothing relevant (maybe [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/289#issuecomment-280351738)), so here is an alternative by adding `<div>` around your custom component.

```html
<style>
.Nested {
    color: blue;
}
</style>
<div class="Nested">
   <Nested />
</div>
```

Maybe you will found something but this one works.

Comment: This approach sets `color: blue` on the entire `Nested` component. I provided an answer below that allows you to targed certain elements within `Nested`.

Comment: @MikeNikles nice one, I just discover svelte 20 minute ago, I didn't know about this.

Comment: You made a nice discovery :)! I've used it for a while but it also took me quite a bit to figure out how this all works with styling nested components.

Comment: Is the `.` inside the style tag needed?

Comment: Yes because you not anymore targeting the `Nested` component but div class above, so in CSS you need to use the dot to trigger it.

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it is like this:

```html
<style lang="stylus">
  section
    // section styles

    :global(img)
    // image styles
</style>
```

This generates css selectors like `section.svelte-15ht3eh img` that only affects the children img tag of the section tag.

No classes or tricks involved there.