# Can't figure our how to remove padding from imported component

Tags: css, svelte, sveltekit

So I'm using the [smui-accordion](https://sveltematerialui.com/demo/accordion) component and I just can't figure out how to remove it's padding!
I've tried putting everywhere zero padding but to no avail...
[image: Padding suffering]

```
<Accordion style="padding: 0">
<Panel  style="padding: 0" bind:open={reviewAccordion} variant="unelevated">
    <Header  style="padding: 0">
        <h3 style="padding: 0"class="mva">Reviews ({reviews_list.length})</h3>
        <div style="padding: 0" class="flex1"></div>
        <div class="mva" style="padding: 0; height: 20px;"><StarRating rating={rating} config={star_config}/></div>
        <IconButton style="padding: 0" slot="icon" toggle pressed={reviewAccordion}>
            <Icon class="material-icons" on>expand_less</Icon>
            <Icon class="material-icons">expand_more</Icon>
        </IconButton>
    </Header>
    <Content  style="padding: 0">
        {#each reviews_list as review, i}
            <div style="padding: 0"><Review review={review}/></div>
        {/each}
    </Content>
</Panel>
```

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59894259/10806546) for how to target components.  The issue is that `style` is actually being read by Svelte as a prop and not HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plasses classes to all SMUI components, so you can do something like:

```html
<Accordion class="myclass" />
```

All you have to remember is to mark those classes as global.
You would probably use some utility class for setting padding to 0, so this is not so much of a problem.

Comment: that's what worked for me! *
    :global(.bra
      .smui-accordion__header__title) {
        padding: 0 !important;
    }

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use "!important" css statement?

```
style="padding: 0 !important"
```

Comment: thanks, but that didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding all those inline just add a css tag above:

```
.smui-accordion .smui-accordion__panel > .smui-accordion__header .smui-accordion__header__title {padding: 0}
```

Above is just whats on console from the accordion css...This will overwrite the third party css and you can have control over it.